# Nm command outpout

Tags: linux, bash

What is the format of `nm` command for static lib files (`*.a`)? How does the command outputs it's info? I'm asking becouse i got strange results using it with `head` command. When i issue just nm:

```
nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libg.a
```

i got:

```
...
dummy.o:
nm: dummy.o: no symbols
```

but when i pipe the result of mn to the head command:

`nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libg.a | head -n 2`

i get:

```
nm: dummy.o: no symbols
...
dummy.o:
```

(where `...` denotes just empty line) which is quite strange while i'd expect just:

```
...
dummy.o:
```

(just first two lines - first - empty and second `dummy.o:`)

PS.
This same strage effect i get when piping to `grep` or `xargs` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is because .a are `ar` archives. To list files in this archive:

```
$ ar t /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libg.a                                                                                                              
dummy.o
```

You could extract dumy.o from libg.a with

```
ar x /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libg.a dummy.o
```

But you'll still not find any symbols. Maybe there arent any symbols to find?

```
$ nm dummy.o                                                                                                                                         
0000000000000000 T __dummy__
```